# How to use return instead of echo in controller action of yii2

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

I have the following view file that upon user performing some function of selecting patient name from the system, the view file calls the controller actionListInvoices that in turn performs some checks and echos an html response via ajax that is displayed to the user. This works well on the localhost, but when I host it in the live server, I get an error bellow:

```
An Error occurred while handling another error:
yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException: Headers already sent in /home/stjamesh/public_html/backend/modules/finance/controllers/PaymentsController.php on line 152. in /home/stjamesh/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php:366
Stack trace:
#0 /home/stjamesh/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php(339): yii\web\Response->sendHeaders()
#1 /home/stjamesh/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/ErrorHandler.php(135): yii\web\Response->send()
#2 /home/stjamesh/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/ErrorHandler.php(111): yii\web\ErrorHandler->renderException(Object(yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException))
#3 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException))
#4 {main}
Previous exception:
yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException: Headers already sent in /home/stjamesh/public_html/backend/modules/finance/controllers/PaymentsController.php on line 152. in /home/stjamesh/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php:366
Stack trace:
#0 /home/stjamesh/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Response.php(339): yii\web\Response->sendHeaders()
#1 /home/stjamesh/public_html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(392): yii\web\Response->send()
#2 /home/stjamesh/public_html/dashboard/index.php(17): yii\base\Application->run()
#3 {main}
```

The solution to this error is suggested that one should use return instead of echo as per the current updates of yii2.

My problem is I am trying to use return but I am not getting anything on the frontend as expected. How do I do this using return with html functions in the action controller?

Here is my view:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use kartik\widgets\ActiveForm;
use wbraganca\dynamicform\DynamicFormWidget;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use kartik\datecontrol\DateControl;
use kartik\builder\Form;

/**
 * @var yii\web\View $this
 * @var app\models\Payments $model
 */

$this->title = 'Add Payment';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Payments', 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;

$js = '
jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterInsert", function(e, item) {
    jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper .panel-title-address").each(function(index) {
        jQuery(this).html("Payment: " + (index + 1))
    });
    jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper .invoice-data").each(function(index) {
        var new_index = index;
        jQuery(this).attr("id", "payment-" + new_index + "-invoice")
    });
});

jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterDelete", function(e) {
    jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper .panel-title-address").each(function(index) {
        jQuery(this).html("Payment: " + (index + 1))
    });
    jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper .invoice-data").each(function(index) {
        var new_index = index;
        jQuery(this).attr("id", "payment-" + new_index + "-invoice")
    });
});
';

$this->registerJs($js);

$this->registerJs(" 
    jQuery(function($){ 
        $(document.body).on('change', '#payments-patient_id', function(){ 
            var select_Id = $(this).attr('id');
            var invoiceId = 'payment-invoice';
            var id1 = $(this).val(); 
            // alert(id1); 
            $.ajax({ 
                type :'GET', cache : false, url : 'list-invoices', data: { patient_id : id1 }, success : function(response) { 
                    alert(response); 
                    $('#'+invoiceId).html(response); 
                } 
            }); 
            return false;
        }); 
    });
");
?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="payment-create">

        <div class="payment-form">

            <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['type' => ActiveForm::TYPE_VERTICAL]); ?>

            <div class="padding-v-md">
                <div class="line line-dashed"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <i class="fa fa-money"></i> Payments
                    <button type="button" class="pull-right add-item btn btn-success btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Payment</button>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body container-items"><!-- widgetContainer -->
                    <div class="item panel panel-default"><!-- widgetBody -->
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <span class="panel-title-address">Make Payment</span>
                            <button type="button" class="pull-right remove-item btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">

                            <?php 
                            echo Form::widget([

                                'model' => $model,
                                'form' => $form,
                                'columns' => 3,
                                'attributes' => [

                                    'receipt_number' => ['type' => Form::INPUT_TEXT, 'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Enter Receipt Number...', 'disabled'=> true]],

                                    'patient_id' => ['type' => Form::INPUT_WIDGET, 'widgetClass'=>'\kartik\widgets\Select2', 'options' => ['data'=>ArrayHelper::map(app\models\Patients::find()->all(), 'id', 'displayDetails'), 'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Patient...']]],

                                    'payment_reference' => ['type' => Form::INPUT_TEXT, 'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Enter Payment Reference...']],
                                ]

                            ]);

                            echo Form::widget([

                                'model' => $model,
                                'form' => $form,
                                'columns' => 3,
                                'attributes' => [

                                    'payment_date' => ['type' => Form::INPUT_WIDGET, 'widgetClass' => DateControl::classname(),'options' => ['type' => DateControl::FORMAT_DATETIME]],

                                    'payment_method_id' => ['type' => Form::INPUT_WIDGET, 'widgetClass'=>'\kartik\widgets\Select2', 'options' => ['data'=>ArrayHelper::map(app\models\PaymentMethod::find()->all(), 'payment_method_id', 'method'), 'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a Payment Method...']]],

                                    'amount' => ['type' => Form::INPUT_TEXT, 'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Enter Amount Paid...']],

                                ]

                            ]);

                            echo Form::widget([

                                'model' => $model,
                                'form' => $form,
                                'columns' => 1,
                                'attributes' => [

                                    'notes' => ['type' => Form::INPUT_TEXTAREA, 'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Enter Notes...', 'maxlength' => 255]],

                                ]

                            ]);?>

                            <div class="invoice-data" id="payment-invoice"></div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
                <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Add Payment' : 'Update Payment', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
                <?= Html::resetButton('Reset', ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) ?>
            </div>

            <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my Controller:

```
<?php

namespace app\modules\finance\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\Payments;
use app\models\PaymentsSearch;
use app\models\FinancialTransactions;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

/**
 * PaymentsController implements the CRUD actions for Payments model.
 */
class PaymentsController extends Controller
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all Payments models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new PaymentsSearch;
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->getQueryParams());

        return $this->render('index', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single Payments model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        // $paymentInvoices = \app\models\PaymentInvoiceLink::find()
        //     ->where(['payment_id' => $id])
        //     ->all();

        $paymentInvoices = \app\models\InvoiceLine::find()
            ->joinWith(['invoiceLinks il'])
            ->where(['il.payment_id' => $id])
            ->all();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->payment_id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('view', [
                'model' => $model,
                'paymentInvoices' => $paymentInvoices,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Payments model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Payments;
        $modelTransactions = new FinancialTransactions;
        $model->receipt_number = $model->receiptNumber;

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $transaction = Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
            try {
                $data = Yii::$app->request->post();

                $period = \app\models\FinancialPeriod::find()
                    ->where(['<=', 'date_from', date("Y-m-d")])
                    ->andWhere(['>=', 'date_to', date("Y-m-d")])
                    ->one();
                $period_id = $period->period_id;
                // create a transaction
                $modelTransactions->debit_account_id = $modelTransactions->defaultDebitAccount($account_code = 'PAYRE');
                $modelTransactions->credit_account_id = $modelTransactions->defaultCreditAccount($account_code = 'ARE');
                $modelTransactions->amount = $data['Payments']['amount'];
                $modelTransactions->notes = 'Payment received from patient';
                $modelTransactions->period_id = $period_id;
                $modelTransactions->branch_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->branch_id;

                if (! ($flag = $modelTransactions->save())) {
                    $transaction->rollBack();
                }

                // create a payment
                $model->created_by = Yii::$app->user->id;
                $model->transaction_id = $modelTransactions->transaction_id;
                $model->amount_unallocated = $modelTransactions->amount;
                $model->branch_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->branch_id;

                if (! ($flag = $model->save())) {
                    $transaction->rollBack();
                }

                if ($flag) {
                    $transaction->commit();
                    \app\models\Invoices::clearInvoices($model->patient_id);
                    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->payment_id]);
                } else {
                    $transaction->rollBack();
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $transaction->rollBack();
            }
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    public function actionTest()
    {
        $result = \app\models\Invoices::clearInvoices(2);
        echo $result;
    }

    /**
     * Displays an array of data model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionListInvoices($patient_id)
    {
        $invoices = \app\models\Invoices::find()->joinWith(['patientVisit pv'])->where(['pv.patient_id' => $patient_id])->andWhere(['or', ['invoices.status_id'=> 1], ['invoices.status_id'=> 4]])->all();

        $count = \app\models\Invoices::find()->joinWith(['patientVisit pv'])->where(['pv.patient_id' => $patient_id])->andWhere(['or', ['invoices.status_id'=> 1], ['invoices.status_id'=> 4]])->count();

        if ($count > 0) {
            $total_amount = 0;
            echo '<table class="table table-bordered table-inverse table-hover">
                <thead class="thead-inverse">
                    <th>Invoice #</th>
                    <th>Invoice Date</th>
                    <th>Due Date</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                    <th>Amount Paid</th>
                    <th>Amount Due</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>';

            foreach($invoices as $invoice){
                echo '<tr>
                        <td>'.$invoice->invoice_number.'</td>
                        <td>'.$invoice->date_created.'</td>
                        <td>'.$invoice->due_date.'</td>
                        <td>'.$invoice->invoiceAmount($invoice->invoice_id).'</td>
                        <td>'.$invoice->paidAmount($invoice->invoice_id).'</td>
                        <td>'.$invoice->amountDue($invoice->invoice_id).'</td>
                    </tr>';
                $total_amount = $total_amount + $invoice->amountDue($invoice->invoice_id) - $invoice->amountUnallocated($invoice->patientVisit->patient_id);
            }
            echo '<tr>
                     <td></td>
                     <td></td>
                     <td></td>
                     <td></td>
                     <td><strong>Previous over-Payment</strong></td>
                     <td class="total">'.$invoice->amountUnallocated($invoice->patientVisit->patient_id).'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                     <td></td>
                     <td></td>
                     <td></td>
                     <td></td>
                     <td><strong>Total Due</strong></td>
                     <td class="total">'.$total_amount.'</td>
                </tr>';
            echo '</tbody></table>';
        } else {
            echo 'Patient has no pending invoice';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing Payments model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->payment_id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing Payments model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the Payments model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return Payments the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Payments::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if I should add anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking to you code  and assuiming as sample the function actionListInvoices
you could build a string with content of the echo and use return instead of echo this way

```
/**
 * Displays an array of data model.
 * @param integer $id
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionListInvoices($patient_id)
{
    $invoices = \app\models\Invoices::find()->joinWith(['patientVisit pv'])->where(['pv.patient_id' => $patient_id])->andWhere(['or', ['invoices.status_id'=> 1], ['invoices.status_id'=> 4]])->all();

    $count = \app\models\Invoices::find()->joinWith(['patientVisit pv'])->where(['pv.patient_id' => $patient_id])->andWhere(['or', ['invoices.status_id'=> 1], ['invoices.status_id'=> 4]])->count();

    if ($count > 0) {
        $total_amount = 0;
        $myEcho = '<table class="table table-bordered table-inverse table-hover">
            <thead class="thead-inverse">
                <th>Invoice #</th>
                <th>Invoice Date</th>
                <th>Due Date</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Amount Paid</th>
                <th>Amount Due</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>';

        foreach($invoices as $invoice){
            $myEcho .= '<tr>
                    <td>'.$invoice->invoice_number.'</td>
                    <td>'.$invoice->date_created.'</td>
                    <td>'.$invoice->due_date.'</td>
                    <td>'.$invoice->invoiceAmount($invoice->invoice_id).'</td>
                    <td>'.$invoice->paidAmount($invoice->invoice_id).'</td>
                    <td>'.$invoice->amountDue($invoice->invoice_id).'</td>
                </tr>';
            $total_amount = $total_amount + $invoice->amountDue($invoice->invoice_id) - $invoice->amountUnallocated($invoice->patientVisit->patient_id);
        }
       $myEcho .=  '<tr>
                 <td></td>
                 <td></td>
                 <td></td>
                 <td></td>
                 <td><strong>Previous over-Payment</strong></td>
                 <td class="total">'.$invoice->amountUnallocated($invoice->patientVisit->patient_id).'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                 <td></td>
                 <td></td>
                 <td></td>
                 <td></td>
                 <td><strong>Total Due</strong></td>
                 <td class="total">'.$total_amount.'</td>
            </tr>';
         $myEcho .= '</tbody></table>';
    } else {
        $myEcho ='Patient has no pending invoice';
    }
    return $myEcho;
}
```

and  (as suggestion)  in a MVC pattern  you should place the code for output in a view and not inside a controller/action  ..  (in controller/action you shoudl retrive  the data and call the render function passing the datas)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it solves the problem for now. On the last note, following the MVC rules, I tried to renderPartial and instead move the HTML code to a view but I was not able to get any response on the user side, how best could I do this?

Comment: normally the renderPartial is used  in a view for reuse common part of code ..so is difficult answer based on you comment  .. for a better evaluation  you could post a new question with the code you have tried  and comment me the comment link  ..

Answer (score 1):

```
$notes = some_raw_content();

\Yii::$app->response->format =  Yii::$app->response::FORMAT_HTML;
// ...or...\Yii::$app->response->format =  Yii::$app->response::FORMAT_RAW;

\Yii::$app->response->content = $notes;
 return;

// .. or ...
 return $notes;
```

References
https://yii2-cookbook-test.readthedocs.io/response-formats/
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-responses